# adding custom header in JSON

Tags: c#, json, soap

I am trying to put Custom Header in my JSON file. Below are the header that the service provider is asking me

Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
hmac-signature:

Below is my partial  code tin include the custom header:

```
  var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri("http://testingwebsite"),
                Headers = {
                            { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), SHA1Key },
                            { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" }

                        }
```

when I tried to add the below line, I got an exception misused header name

```
 { HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/json" }
```

any help will be apprecaited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think using .ToString() on those Types is the right way to go. For example, ContentType.ToString() is likely "ContentType". That is just not a valid http header. I'd trying just using the string "Content-Type".

```
    { "Content-Type", "application/json" }
```